# Is that possible to build an ASP.Net Core web application using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to put all the codes that is needed to create an ASP.NetCore Web Application in a text file and then read it in an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application and compile it using Roslyn and save it as a dll file.
I tried a lot. I could do that for a Console application but not for a web application.
This is what I did

```
public void Load(string id, string code, IEnumerable<string> allowedAssemblyNames, IEnumerable<Type> allowedTypes, string path)
{
    try
    {
        var _references = new List<MetadataReference>();
        foreach (var assemblyName in allowedAssemblyNames)
        {
            _references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory() + assemblyName + ".dll"));
        }

        foreach (var type in allowedTypes)
        {
            _references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(type.Assembly.Location));
        }
        _references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("netstandard").Location));


        var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(
            OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
            reportSuppressedDiagnostics: true,
            optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release,
            generalDiagnosticOption: ReportDiagnostic.Error,
            allowUnsafe: false);

        var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code, options: new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.Latest, kind: SourceCodeKind.Regular));
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(id, new[] { syntaxTree }, _references, options);

        assemblyLoadContext = new AssemblyLoadContext(id, true);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var result = compilation.Emit(ms);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Have you read and tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/net-core-cross-platform-code-generation-with-roslyn-and-net-core

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Thank you. I tried that page before. It shows how to create different classes and run it but I need to create a new website from the scratch. It contains `Program` class, `main` method, `Startup` class and etc. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time on it, based on [a discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37206), it seems it is not possible to do that.

The answer given was:

> I believe it's considered unsupported by .NET Core to compile directly
>   against System.Private.CoreLib.dll. In general, it will probably be
>   quite difficult to compile an application without using the `dotnet`
>   tool and MSBuild, as you will have to effectively replicate all the
>   logic that goes into picking the appropriate reference assemblies,
>   then generating the right executing environment for the .NET Core
>   shared loader.